# how to remove unselected option of select box by jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-select

i want to remove all unselected option of Particular select box by j-query and java script simple code

example : if i select test- 1 option of first select box, than all unselected option remove of first select box , and this condition apply on all select box

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mymultiSelect" onchange="myfun()">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect" onchange="myfun()">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect" onchange="myfun()">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect" onchange="myfun()">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect" onchange="myfun()">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>

<script>

function myfun(){
var foo = [];
$('.mymultiSelect :selected').each(function(i, selected){
  
  if($(selected).val() != 0)
  {
    foo[i] = $(selected).val();
    alert(foo[i]);
  }
  
});

}


</script>
```

Comment: Every Select box can be selected separately or you want to remove all unselected from all select boxes on selection changed of first select box ?

Answer (score 7):

Try something like this :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.mymultiSelect').on('change', function() {
    $(this).find('option').not(':selected').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking

Answer (score 2):

Im not quite sure I understand correctly.

My code uses the value that is selected and removes it from all the other selects. I hope this works for you.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.mymultiSelect').on('change', function() {
    $('.mymultiSelect').not($(this)).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
<select class="mymultiSelect">
 <option value="0">-select-</option>
 <option value="1">test - 1</option>
 <option value="2">test - 2</option>
 <option value="3">test - 3</option>
 <option value="4">test - 4</option>
</select>
```